# Laravel5 file Upload via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

When I am uploading file showing some error. Error details and file contents are given below. Could you please check and help me to solve this issue?

**Error**

```
 Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

 in RouteCollection.php line 201

at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 188

at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 140

at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 746

at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 655

at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631

at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236

etc
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/ambition/update', [
    'before'  => 'csrf',
    'as'      => 'tagambitionupdate',
    'uses'    => 'TagambitionController@update'
]);
```

**TagambitionController.php**

```
public function update(TagambitionRequest $request)
    {
        $userTagID     = $request->hiddenid;
        $file          = $request->file('file');
        dd($file);
    }
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Upload files of ambition tags begin*/
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            alert('hai');
            var form      = $("#addForm")[0];
            var formdata  = new FormData(form);
            formdata.append('file', 'file');
            $.ajax({
                url : "/ambition/update",
                type: "POST",
                data : formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
        /* Upload files of ambition tags end*/
    });
```

**forntend.blade.php**

```
<div class="tag-handler-ambition-response">
                        <form id="addForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><span id="tag-ambition-append">Test</span><input name="file" type="file" id="file" ><input name="hiddenid" id="hiddenid" type="hidden" value='{{ $id }}' ><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><button class="btn btn-default" id="submit" >Submit</button></form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you please do a `console.log(url)` inside your javascript script? and post the result? Are you sure you are posting in the correct url?

Comment: @ Harry Geo, My console is showing error "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://www.ct.dev/ct". I am posting the correct url

Comment: That's the result of the failed request, I asked about your url? are you sure you are posting at `http://yourdomain.com/ambition/update` also take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: @HarryGeo, yes posting url is correct. Firebug Net showing -----------------------------25603393529504
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hiddenid"

28
-----------------------------25603393529504
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

wdqLkfj10vaj9efEV2dncm3v6E0KLw52ArQXbXCl
-----------------------------25603393529504--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my result. I have changed the button click function to form submit. Please check my code below. I can upload files without refreshing page using Laravel5 and jQuery ajax.

**jS**

```
$("#addForm_"+response.id).submit(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var form      = $("#addForm_"+response.id)[0];
                            var formdata  = new FormData(form);
                            formdata.append('file', 'file_'+response.id);
                            $.ajax({
                                url : "/ambition/update",
                                type: "POST",
                                data : formdata,
                                processData: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                success:function(data){
                                }
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });
```